# Get cursor X and Y coordinates on graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to get the x, y values of the cursor on matplotlib graph.
How can I do it?

[image: mentioned values]

Comment: Have a look at [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

If the location of the coordinates does not matter, you can use this example:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/cursor_demo_sgskip.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, using `ginput` might be simpler. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html